# Animal movement dataset

Tags: data-request, geospatial, time-series, biology

I am looking for a animal movement dataset  with at least 50  animals recorder for at least 100 times all together.

I know https://www.movebank.org/node/2 but I didn't find what I need.

Can someone help me?